# Extract property array from Laravel Collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-collection

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and I have one collection formatted like this:

```
$categories = [
   {
      "id":1,
      "sub_categories":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "category_id":1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":7,
      "sub_categories":[
         {
            "id":5,
            "category_id":7,
         },
         {
            "id":6,
            "category_id":7
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I need to extract all sub_categories arrays but I can't find a way to access the data inside that property. Based on `$categories` collection, I'm expecting to create a new one with this format:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "category_id":1
   },
   {  
      "id":5,
      "category_id":7
   },
   {  
      "id":6,
      "category_id":7
   }
]
```

I've tried applying **map** and **pluck** to `$categories` but it retrieves an array filled with *null*.

Comment: `$categories->pluck("sub_categories")->flatten(1)` might do it

Comment: nope... now it gives me an array filled with null.

Comment: I tried pluck and it worked, in what way did you retrieve the collection?

Comment: this way: Category::where('team_id', Auth::user()->current_team_id)->with('subCategories')->get(). You made me try the pluck method with the relationship name and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `flatMap` will do exactly what you want.  I'm not sure why it returns items as an array to the callback but here's what worked for me...

```
$categories = collect((object) [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'sub_categories' => [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'category_id' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 7,
        'sub_categories' => [
            [
                'id' => 5,
                'category_id' => 6
            ],
            [
                'id' => 6,
                'category_id' => 7
            ]
        ]
    ],
]);

dd($categories->flatMap(function($category) {
    return $category['sub_categories'];
}));
```

Comment: flatMap thumb up! TBH I never tried it. Great to know it.

Answer (score 0):

`pluck` method did the trick. Looks like if the property you are trying to get has been retrieved via Eloquent Relationships - Eager Loading, you have to pass the relationship's name to `pluck`.

I'm getting my collection from DB like this:

```
Category::where('team_id', Auth::user()->current_team_id)->with('subCategories')->get()‌​;
```

so I had to call the pluck method as `$categories->pluck('subCategories');` instead of  `$categories->pluck('sub_categories');`